# Ionic 4 Android Application fails to load the source on build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an Application build with Ionic 4. When I use to build and install the Application with reload option it works (`ionic cordova run android --l --c` ). But when I do `ionic cordova build android` and deploying in a device, it does not load anything and results in blank screen. On inspecting, the following error got printed.

```
polyfills.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cordova.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
vendor.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
styles.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
runtime.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
/assets/icon/favicon.png:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Researched through and added delay in config.xml file `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />` but that didn't worked. Also removed and add android, still no luck.

If I connect the device to machine and running the application directly to the device with reload command, it is throwing the error **The connection to the server was unsuccessful.**

Ionic version - 4.10.3; 
Ionic-Android version - android 6.3.0; 
Cordova - 7.1.0

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall the platform again

Comment: Did that but no luck

Comment: In the index.html, change base href="/" to base href="./" try this because the index file not initiated to load the resource

Comment: I tried changing base href="/" to base href="./". The application works but in a while after the launch, it throws an error "The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html). Weird behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Try this
Ionic Cordova platform remove Android

Then

1. Ionic cordova platform add android
2. Ionic cordova prepare android
3. Ionic cordova build android
4. Ionic cordova run android

   If u want to use emulator then use

   Ionic cordova run android -l

Answer (score 4):

I changed the index.html from

```
<base href="/" />
```

to

```
<base href="." />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue this morning - this is not an ideal solution but I removed my entire local repo and cloned it again from the source.

Not a nice fix but it works.